# Django: ChoiceField not returning options

Tags: django, django-forms, forms

I am having an issue trying to get a simple choice field to return its options to a html page in my application. I have been looking at several other questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991501/initial-value-for-django-form-choice-field-ignored), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875455/html-tags-for-choicefield-in-django) and some online tutorials but cant seem to get it right.

My current code does not return the dropdown, it only returns the submit button.

Optimally I would like to return the countries in a Dropdown list with the option of making it a required field.

I am able to return similar views using models.Model using this approach but cant seem to get the ChoiceField from forms.Form working.

Any help is much appreciated, Thanks.

**models.py**

```
from django import forms

class CountryChoiceTwo(forms.Form):

    IRELAND = 'IR'
    ENGLAND = 'EN'
    FRANCE = 'FR'
    SCOTLAND = 'SC'
    WALES = 'WA'
    ITALY = 'IT'

    COUNTRY = (
        (IRELAND, "Ireland"),
        (ENGLAND, "England"),
        (FRANCE, "France"),
        (SCOTLAND, "Scotland"),
        (WALES, "Wales"),
        (ITALY, "Italy"),
               )

    origin = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), choices=COUNTRY, initial= IRELAND)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.origin
```

**views.py**

```
from books.models import CountryChoiceTwo

def ContactForm(request):

    form = CountryChoiceTwo(initial={'origin':COUNTRY[1]})   
    return render(request, 'country_choice.html', {'form': form} )
```

**country_choices.html**

```
<h2>What country are you from?</h2>


<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{form.as_p}}


<input type="submit" value="Vote" />               
</form>
```

Comment: When you say returning, do you mean that the dropdown is not appearing on the rendered HTML page or that once selected it doesn't get submitted to the view?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that the dropdown is not even appearing in the HTML page

Comment: Is the rest of the template appearing ? (Like the "What country are you from?" part

Comment: and you aren't getting an error for `COUNTRY` being undefined? It isn't defined in your view function. You would need to do `CountryChoiceTwo.COUNTRY`

Comment: No it is not giving me an error. I have another view "def Country(request):" in my views.py file which will at least return some data from another model. I can remove this now in case it is confusing things.

Comment: Done. I never thought about the other model getting in the way. Thank you so much. If you want to submit your suggestion in the form of an answer i would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COUNTRY` is not defined in the scope of your view function.

You can reference `COUNTRY` from your form by prefixing it with the class name:

```
def ContactForm(request):
    form = CountryChoiceTwo(initial={'origin': CountryChoiceTwo.COUNTRY[1]})
    return render(request, 'country_choice.html', {'form': form} )
```